# Why may we only distribute a negative on the numerator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From habit and convention, I'm well aware that $$-\frac{3x+4y}{5z-8w}$$ is equivalent to $$\frac{-3x-4y}{5z-8w}$$ and it requires distributing the negative across the numerator.

However, I have no good explanation as to why the denominator can't be distributed a negative across it, since $5/-3 = -(5/3)$ and the fact that this follows from the previous intuition:

$$\frac{3x+4y}{-5z-8w} = \frac{3x+4y}{-1(5z+8w)} =   -\frac{3x+4y}{5z+8w} $$

The only thing I can think of is it would be a change of base which might break equivalence, but I can't refute the statement above.

Comment: You're correct:  You can distribute a negative of a fraction, over the numerator, or denominator, just not both.

Comment: Who ever said that you can't distribute over the denominator ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust No one, it's just that it usually isn't helpful in algebra as functions with only the same base can be worked on.. for reasons that have never been made aware to me

Comment: "functions with only the same base" ??? What's that ? And what's the relation to your question ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust what I'm trying to get across is I'm wondering why I have to find a common denominator when evaluating two fractions in the first place

Comment: When you need to add them. That's a completely different issue.

Comment: Indeed, sanstar:  You asked about multiply a fraction by $-1$.  If you keep adding to your list :  "also, why...?", "and for that matter, why...?" then you've overextended your question.  If there are other matters about adding fractions that you do not understand, think carefully, and ask a different question, providing more context than you provided here.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct about distributing the negative: $$-1 = \frac {-1}{1} = \frac 1{-1}.$$ You can distribute a negative of a fraction (negative 1 times a fraction), over the numerator, or denominator, just not both.

$$-\left(\frac ab\right) = \frac {-a}{b} = \frac a{-b} = -\left(\frac{a}b\right)$$

In your case, distributing the negative across $(5z -8w)$ means $$-(5z - 8w) = -5z + 8w = (8w-5z)$$

Comment: Excuse how naive this sounds, but what about denominators then prohibit me from combining something such as $\frac{3x+4y}{-5z-8w} -\frac(2x+y}{z^2 + w}$ by finding a common denominator? Why must algebra be done on the numerator only and only when the denominators are of the same form?

Comment: I think you are confused here.  Subtracting $$\frac {3x+4}{-5z+8w} - \frac {2x+y}{z^2 + w} $$ gives us $$\frac {3x+4}{-5z+8w} + \frac{-2x -y}{z^2 +w} $$  In either case, you are able to find the common denominator.

Comment: The best way to do so would be using the denominator $(-5z+8w)(z^2 + w)$ as the common denominator.  And continuing from there.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity of my question. I'm fine with that, my question is more general- why do the fractions need to have a common denominator to be worked on in the first place? Why not the numerator? What  is it about the denominator that distinguishes itself from the numerator where it has that requirement?

Comment: Because the denominators are dividing the numerators, respectively, whereas the numerators can be seen as factors:  E.g. $\frac a b+\frac cd = \frac {a d +bc}{bd}$. And wrt numerators as factors, $$\frac ab + \frac cd = a\cdot\frac 1b + c\cdot \frac 1d$$  So numerators and denominators have different properties, but wrt distribution of a  negative (-1), we can distribute it across the numerator, or the denominator, but not both.  When it comes to any constant multiplying a fraction, **other than -1, 1,**  we must multiply only the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can distribute a negative over the denominator, but what you did is not right, since the negative of $5z -8w$ is $-5z+8w$

So, you should have done:

$$-\frac{3x+4y}{5z-8w}=\frac{3x+4y}{-1(5z-8w)}=\frac{3x+4y}{-5z+8w}$$

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that distributing multiplication by $+1$ and $-1$ over the the numerator are special cases of a general distributive law, but the only examples of distribution over the denominator, since the value being distributed must square to $1$ in this case.

Answer (score 2):

$-1$ is represented by both fractions $(-1)/1$ and $1/(-1)$. You can use the rule for the product of fractions:

$$-\frac pq=\frac{-1}1\frac ab=\frac{-a}b$$ 
or
$$-\frac pq=\frac1{-1}\frac ab=\frac a{-b}.$$

Answer (score 1):

your solution is wrong, writing
$$-\frac{3x+4y}{5z-8w}=-\frac{(3x-4y)(-1)}{(5z-8w)(-1)}=\frac{3x+4y}{8w-5z}$$